# How to implement UICollectionView within ViewController.swift using Swift 3 for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, ios10

I am following along with Brian Voong for his tutorial:
https://youtu.be/kecV6xPTTr8?list=PL0dzCUj1L5JHfozquTVhV4HRy-1A_aXlv

I am using the following code in ViewController.swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let collectionView: UICollectionView {
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    return cv
}()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    collectionView.frame = view.frame


        }
```

I get two error messages which I don't understand as it is running for him:

1. "'let' declarations cannot be computed properties" on 'let
   collectionView: UICollectionView {' line.
2. '}()' provides another
   error message "Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated
   by ';'"

Would it be a function declaration or has swift been updated not to allow this syntax. Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing an equal sign:

```
let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
```

Example :

```
let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    return cv
}()
```